# Set state in async function in React using two requests

Tags: async-await, react-hooks

I would like to fetch to APIs and store them in React hooks. The following does not work. When I do a similar pattern with just one fetch (no Promise.all) it works fine.

```
  const [first, setFirst] = useState(null);
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  async function getData() {

    let [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
      fetch('url1'),
      fetch('url2'),
    ]);

    const data1 = await res1.json();
    const data2 = await res2.json();

    setFirst(data1);
    setSecond(data2);

    console.log(data1); //Array as expected
    console.log(first); //null
  }
```

Comment: FYI,
it will be better if we will be able to know how 'getData' is cooded.

Comment: mutating state is an async process in react. you can't immediately see the results. if you want, you can add another useEffect with dependencies like [first, second] and log them as they're changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State updates using the `setState` function returned by the `useState` hook are asynchronous (but React doesn't expose that promise to you).

If you want to react to changes in a state value from the `useState` hook (e.g. logging the value to the console when it changes), you can do so by [including it as a dependency in the `useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect):

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(first);
}, [first]);
```